# Creating Linen texture with CSS?

Tags: css

[Linen](http://elixirgraphics.com/images/blog/final.jpg)

Is it possible to create Apple's linen texture with CSS? Something like background gradient, to avoid the slow speed of an image.

Comment: I got an alternative solution:use base64 images instead. I don't know if this makes the image loads faster or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the noise feature of CSS can get you a long way to creating a pure CSS texture. Play around with http://www.noisetexturegenerator.com/ to see the possibilities. If you put both opacity and density you can get a striped pattern that somewhat resembles cloth.

A special mention goes to this article, for using css gradients to give your noise texture that little extra something:
http://www.rd2inc.com/blog/2013/01/tips-and-tricks-css3-gradients-and-textures/

Be advised that the noise feature is pretty new and isn't supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think gradient is possible. follow the link:[Speed Up with CSS3 Gradients](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)